# Defining local maven repo to SBT

Tags: windows, maven, sbt

I've managed to get this thing working once but it's broken again..adding third slash is not helping anymore. Support for this on Windows is somehow broken.

I have in `build.scala`:

```
val localM2Repo = "Local Maven Repository" at "file:///" + Path.userHome + "/.m2/repository"
```

When I try to compile:

```
[warn] ==== Local Maven Repository: tried
[warn]   file:///C:/Users/tomaszk/.m2/repository/mcloud-integration-git/mcloud-integration-git-parent/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mcloud-integration-git-parent-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

So I checked whether or not the file existed with Scala REPL:

```
val u = new java.net.URI("file:///C:/Users/tomaszk/.m2/repository/mcloud-integration-git/mcloud-integration-git-parent/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mcloud-integration-git-parent-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom")
val f = new java.io.File(u)
f.exists

res26: Boolean = true
```

What could be reason for the failure?

Comment: Could you give `"Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"` a try? Note the use of `.absolutePath` and only two slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've got this running.

The artifact that couldn't have been resolved was referenced in .ivy2 folder. Why? I have no idea. Just saw that sbt logged that it cannot delete old version of the artefact in .ivy2 folder.

So I deleted the whole .ivy2 folder and afterwards SBT picked up the jar without no problems.

I've tried to reproduce it but with no luck so I cannot fire a ticket unfortunatelly.